# Switching between FIPS and Standard AWS Endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-quicksight

I have an application that uses the AWS endpoint "us-east-2.quicksight.aws.amazon.com". One of my customers has a security standard that does not to allow any endpoint that still supports TLS V1.0. Does anyone know if I can simply change the endpoints in my application to use "**FIPS**-us-east-2.quicksight.aws.amazon.com"? It appears to work in test, but seems like too easy of a fix, so curious if there are any other issues/considerations that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with a given AWS service in a `FIPS-compliant` manner, you must use the [FIPS](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/fips/) endpoints (different than the standard endpoints) with your `FIPS-compliant` client